# Does lead paint block Superman's X-Ray Vision?

Tags: dc, superman

It's well known that Superman's X-Ray Vision can see through solid objects, except for lead, similar to real-world x-rays. Would [lead paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_paint) prevent Superman's X-Ray Vision from working? It's not solid lead, but it does have a fair amount of the mineral in it.

Comment: I'd say that it would either fully block his x-ray vision or at least partially block it. I mean, why wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think any serious canon allows that limitation but for some reason I vaguely remember an old cartoon that mentioned it. Possibly season 1 episode 28 of the 1960s New Adventures of Superman?

Comment: @TheIronCheek Any chance you could look into that? I don't own that series.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I don't either. I got the season/episode reference from a Google search. Looks like you can watch the episode on YouTube for $1.99, though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHWe0riWMAs

Comment: @Thunderforge - I'm sure there are dubious ways to watch it online as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By process of elimination, no. No such limitation was ever shown in the early Superman comics, and in the 40's and 50's lead paint was the norm.

Comment: What about a tank of leaded gasoline? :-p